# ¿Por qué no se crea el documento de texto en el siguiente código de Arduino?

Tags: arduino

```
#include <Wire.h> // Reloj
#include <RTClib.h> //poner el reloj en hora u obtener sus datos.
#include <SD.h>//con el modulo sd
#include <SPI.h> // Incluimos las librerias estandar para trabajar 
#include <DHT.h> // Temperatura y Humedad


//-----------------Variables----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int Temp,
    HumR,
    Tyh = 14;
int Hum1, Humt1 = A0;
int Rele1 = 8;
int pinCS= 53;

// las variables son variables de tamaño extendido para almacenamiento de números y almacenan 32 bits (4 bytes)
unsigned long interval=1800000; 
unsigned long previousMillis=0;

    RTC_DS3231 rtc;
    //vectores donde se van a almacenar los dias de la semana y los meses del año
    String daysOfTheWeek[7] = { "Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado" };
    String monthsNames[12] = { "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo",  "Junio", "Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre" };

    DHT dht(Tyh, DHT11);
//-------------------------------Archivo----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//archivo que se crea en la terjeta colocada en el modulo sd
File Datos;    
//-----------------------------Hora y fecha------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void printDateSD(DateTime date)
{
 Datos.print(date.year(), DEC);
 Datos.print('/');
 Datos.print(date.month(), DEC);
 Datos.print('/');
 Datos.print(date.day(), DEC);
 Datos.print(" (");
 Datos.print(daysOfTheWeek[date.dayOfTheWeek()]);
 Datos.print(") ");
 Datos.print(date.hour(), DEC);
 Datos.print(':');
 Datos.print(date.minute(), DEC);
 Datos.print(':');
 Datos.print(date.second(), DEC);
 Datos.println();
}


void printDate(DateTime date)
{
 Serial.print(date.year(), DEC);
 Serial.print('/');
 Serial.print(date.month(), DEC);
 Serial.print('/');
 Serial.print(date.day(), DEC);
 Serial.print(" (");
 Serial.print(daysOfTheWeek[date.dayOfTheWeek()]);
 Serial.print(") ");
 Serial.print(date.hour(), DEC);
 Serial.print(':');
 Serial.print(date.minute(), DEC);
 Serial.print(':');
 Serial.print(date.second(), DEC);
 Serial.println();
}

void reloj(RTC_DS3231 rtc){
 if (!rtc.begin()) {
 Serial.println(F("Couldn't find RTC"));
 while (1);
 }

 // Si se ha perdido la corriente, fijar fecha y hora
 if (rtc.lostPower()) {
 // Fijar a fecha y hora de compilacion
 //rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
 rtc.adjust(DateTime(2019, 02, 06, 18, 59, 0));
 }
}
//---------------------------------------DATOS------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void datosSD()
 {
  Datos.print("Humedad relativa ");
  Datos.println(HumR);
  Datos.print("Tempratura ");
  Datos.print(Temp);
  Datos.println(" C");
  Datos.print("Intensidad luminica ");
  Datos.print("Humedad planta 1 ");
  Datos.println(Hum1);
  }

void datos()
{
  Serial.print("Humedad relativa ");
  Serial.println(HumR);
  Serial.print("Tempratura ");
  Serial.print(Temp);
  Serial.println(" C");
  Serial.print("Intensidad luminica ");

  Serial.print("Humedad planta 1 ");
  Serial.println(Hum1);
  }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
   dht.begin();
  pinMode(pinCS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Rele1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (Humt1, INPUT);
  reloj(rtc);

  if(SD.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Modulo SD listo para usar");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("\t Inicializacion del modulo SD Fallida");
    return; //En caso de que no se pueda inicializar el modulo SD
    // El programa llegará a su fin.
  }

}

void loop() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now(); //obtener hora actual
  Hum1 = analogRead(Humt1);
  HumR = dht.readHumidity();
  Temp = dht.readTemperature();


  unsigned long currentMillis = millis(); 
  if ((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillis) >= interval) {

  printDate(now);
  datos();
  Datos = SD.open("Datos.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  Serial.println("Reescribiendo archivo");
  Serial.println();
  printDateSD(now);
  datosSD();
  Datos.close();

  previousMillis = millis();
  }

//---Relé 1---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(Temp<=40 and Temp>=35  )
 {
  digitalWrite(Rele1, HIGH);
    delay (2000);
    digitalWrite(Rele1, LOW); 
  }else{ if(Hum1 >=0  && Hum1 <= 500  )
 {
   digitalWrite(Rele1, LOW); 
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(Rele1, HIGH);
    delay (2000);
    digitalWrite(Rele1, LOW); 
    } 

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

En `if(SD.begin())` faltan `pinCS`.
Prueba esto: `if(SD.begin(pinCS))`